# Change base_url in codeigniter before publsihing

Tags: php, codeigniter, url, publish

I want to publish my codeigniter website.

Now it is located in '../htdocs/site/' folder. and the base_url is:

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/site';
```

Should I copy the 'site' folder to real server and change the base_url like this:

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://example.com/site';
```

or there is another way so that I can hide '/site' in the URL ?

This is my first project and your help is highly appreciated.

Update:

```
Root/
      -Application1
      -System1
      -Site1/
                    -index.php
                    -css
                    -js
                   -images
      -Application2
      -System2
      -Site2/
                    -index.php
                    -css
                    -js
                   -images
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to duplicate your application for each environement. Codeigniter can handle multiple configurations. You just need to set one folder per environment.

Let's suppose the following organization :

```
Root/
      -Application
      -System
      -Assets           
         -css
         -js
         -images

      -index.php
```

We will have 3 environments: Dev/Testing/Production.

We know that our application will have a different base_url and database conf depending on the environment. It means that we will need to modify config.php and database.php each time we will move our app from an env to an other.

CodeIgniter provides us an easy way to do that :

http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/environments.html

http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/config.html#environments

We just need to set 3 folders inside application/config

```
-application
      -config
         - development
         - testing
         - production
```

Inside those new folders, just place the config files which will be different on each environement. In our case, config.php and database.php

```
-application
      -config
         - development 
              -config.php
              -database.php
         - testing
              -config.php
              -database.php 
         - production
              -config.php
              -database.php
         - autoload.php
         - ...
```

Finally, in the root index.php just have to modify the following line to tell CI in which environement it is :

```
define('ENVIRONMENT', 'development'); //for dev env
define('ENVIRONMENT', 'testing'); //for testing env
define('ENVIRONMENT', 'production'); //for prod env
```

development/testing/production are defaults environements in CI but you can create your own just by creating your folders in application/config and modifying the switch in the root index.php :

```
switch (ENVIRONMENT)
{
    case 'development':
        error_reporting(E_ALL);
    break;
    case 'server':
        error_reporting(E_ALL);
    break;
    case 'testing':
    case 'production':
        error_reporting(0);
    break;
   /*CUSTOM ENV :*/
    case 'custom_env':
        error_reporting(E_ALL);
    break;
    default:
        exit('The application environment is not set correctly.');
}
```

Comment: thanks but you have not answered my question. In your example there is only one website in the root. but what if there are two or more websites and each of them has index.php file.

Comment: You don't need to separate you application in different folders. In case of multiple applications, you can mix my answer with that strategy : http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/managing_apps.html .

Comment: but what if there are absolutely different applications with different domains. for example, there can be 5 wordpress websites, 7 codeigniter websites, 3 joomla websites, 6 php websites etc. Or maybe it is possible to rename index.php file for each website?

Comment: Indeed that will not work in this case, but then it is more an issue about server/dns configuration than codeigniter's setup.

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
Move file from site directory to root directory and change root path index.php

$system_path = '../site/system';
$application_folder = '../site/application';

to 
$system_path = '../system';
$application_folder = '../application';

Change baseurl:$config['base_url'] = 'http://example.com/';
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. Actually I wonder what will happen if I copy second website to my root. There will be two index.php files? I thought it would be possible to create one folder for each website in the root (with relevand index.php file and css js files). Pls see the updated part of question.

Answer (score 0):

Just copy contents of 'site'(not site folder just contents) to  public html in server
then set base_url as 'http://example.com/

Nb:if using base in htaccess change it to just /

Comment: The problem is that there will be more sites in the same root later. Please check the updated part of my answer to see how I would like to organize the structure.